# Return value of process

Tags: .net, c++, winapi, process, return-value

How can I get the return value of a process? Basically I'm **[ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28VS.85%29.aspx)()**ing a .NET process from a DLL (in C++). The process does its task, but now I want to know whether it succeeded or failed. How to do that in WinAPI or MFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762154.aspx) instead so you can get a handle to the process which was launched. You should then be able to use [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189.aspx) to obtain the exit code.

(I've left this answer here despite the similar one from MSalters, as I suspect you're using `ShellExecute` deliberately to get the shell behaviour instead of explicitly creating the process.)

Answer (score 5):

Use CreateProcess(). keep the process handle and call GetExitCodeProcess() when the process handle becomes signalled.

Answer (score 0):

ShellExecute() in its native is 16-bit call, so it is not intended to give feedback / callback althought you can saerch thread / process / memory adress ( if you locate usable memory space ) and its flags ( if there would be no such a thing as bloody flags, WinAPI (32-bit) would be much simpatic than it is now ).
To provide full feedback, you can try extended version or CreateProcess() function with is pure 32-bit function.
Unfourtinately I cannot give you any detailed info about flags / Lparameters and other API parameters.

Besides, mainly all executive function/procedures/methods retur booleans, so you always can start with [if..then] statement as return provider.

Opps, while i was writing this, already three answers were made.